# linked list and an Invalid read of size 4

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I've been implementing a linked list to scrape the rust out of my development skills, but noticed valgrind reports an Invalid read of size 4 during my test of removing middle elements.

> ```
> ==1197== Invalid read of size 4
> ==1197==    at 0x804885C: main (list.c:135)
> ==1197==  Address 0x426e76c is 4 bytes inside a block of size 12 free'd
> ==1197==    at 0x40257ED: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
> ==1197==    by 0x804875E: list_remove (list.c:112)
> ==1197==    by 0x8048857: main (list.c:137)
> ```

The code in the main that triggers this is:

> ```
>     for (iter = l2->head; iter; iter = iter->next) {
>             if (iter->n >= 10 && iter->n <= 14)
>                     list_remove(l2, iter);
> ```

The remove function is:

```
void list_remove(struct list *list, struct node *node)
{
        if (node == list->head && node == list->tail) {
                list->head = list->tail = NULL;
        }
        else if (node == list->head) {
                list->head = node->next;
                list->head->prev = NULL;
        }
        else if (node == list->tail) {
                list->tail = node->prev;
                list->tail = NULL;
        }
        else  {
                struct node *prev, *next;
                prev = node->prev;
                next = node->next;
                prev->next = next;
                next->prev = prev;
        }

        free(node);
}
```

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are freeing the value in the loop, then dereferencing it to get at its "next" pointer. You need a temp value to do this right:

```
    for (iter = l2->head; iter; iter = next) {
            next = iter->next;
            if (iter->n >= 10 && iter->n <= 14)
                    list_remove(l2, iter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing the `iter` pointer when you `free(node)`. Then you try to read from `iter->next` which doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

Hhm... All you have to do, is **read** the valgrind message.

- invalid read here: `main (list.c:135)` - that's `iter->next`,
- from a freed location, memory freed here: `list_remove (list.c:112)`, that's `free(node);`.

Just cache the next pointer before removing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand what exactly was going on, as there is at least 2 reads in the line 135.

Comment: so? add some trace messages and you'll see.